# Zapier regex: match after word

Tags: zapier

I am trying to extract string after a word match in Zapier, but it's not really working.

Input text is an email from Gmail and the search patter is the following:

```
(?<=Lic:        )[^.\s]*
```

Example on regex101.com is working:

https://regex101.com/r/nSNnNM/1

On zapier I can't get it to match:

[image]

Comment: can you update your question with a screenshot of the input fields?

Comment: Try `(?<=Lic:        )[^.\s+]*` Zapier may need the `+` so that random white spaces are skipped. More code would help, otherwise this is a very open ended question that we can only guess on.